# How to programmatically get scrollbar to botton of canvas - tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to programmatically set the vertical scrollbar to the bottom of the canvas. (The vertical scrollbar appears after many rows of widgets are added to the GUI and the vscrollbar works as desired.) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `yview_moveto` method to adjust the view in the y direction:

```
self.canvas.yview_moveto(1.0)
```